# Running mono on Windows with Winforms applications exits immediately

Tags: c#, winforms, mono

I've got mono 3.2.3 installed. When I try to run a Winforms application - even one as simple as the default template when creating a new project - mono exits immediately with exit code 1 without doing anything, and with no output. Console Applications work fine.

This is from trying to run it in Cygwin:

[image: Screenshot of the issue]

Answer (score 1):

By changing the project's Output Type to Console Application I got error messages in the console.

> Unhandled Exception:
>   System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for System.Windows.Forms.WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext ---> System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for System.Windows.Forms.ThemeEngine ---> System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for System.Windows.Forms.ThemeWin32Classic ---> System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for System.Drawing.KnownColors ---> System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for System.Drawing.GDIPlus ---> System.DllNotFoundException: /tmp/install/lib/libgdiplus.so

Googling that lead me to a page in mono's bug tracker: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=8309

Apparently, this bug was already fixed a year ago, but only merged into mono 3.4.0. The workaround is to edit the file

```
$MONO/etc/mono/config
```

and remove the two offending lines:

```
<dllmap dll="gdiplus" target="/tmp/install/lib/libgdiplus.so" />
<dllmap dll="gdiplus.dll" target="/tmp/install/lib/libgdiplus.so" />
```

This fixed the issue.